# full join 2 tables in mariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

I have 2 tables

```
Table1
Year,Month, data     
2017,1,2
2018,2,10

Table2
Year,Month,data2
2017,1,5
2019,2,2
```

I am trying to consolidate the tables into 1 tables where we get all rows from both tables as follows.

```
Year,Month,data,data2
2017 ,1,2,5
2018,2,10,NULL
2019,2,NULL,2
```

It seems like standard outer joins will not work here and I can't use Union ALL either
Is there some kind of Outer join query to accomplish this?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: @philipxy ,Actually I did Google and search SO and I indicated that some use of Union and joins seemed needed in the question.  The closest resembling question on SO I could find is: How to do a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL?  but that question does not address the additional subtlety here,  that the tables need to be padded with additional column before performing the full outer join.  If you see this as a duplicate please provide link, I couldn't find one with same structure.  Please be constructive,  what would your recommended title be? I don't think the solutions proposed are easy to find!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a UNION for obtain allthe year and month from both tables and use left join for relate this to  table1 and table2

```
select a.Year , a.Month, b.data, c.data2
from (
  select Year,Month
  from Table1
  union 
  select Year,Month
  from Table2
) a 
left join  table1 b  on a.Year = b.Year and a.month = b. month 
left  join table2 c on a.Year = c.Year and a.month = c. month
```

Comment: WOW,  I never would have thought such a simple merge operation would need such a complex query!

Comment: @shev72   .. for SQL this is not complex .. if you take a look  .. the union subquery return  the value you need  as  main values  .. the two left join just retrive the value you need form each table  .

Comment: Maybe one day, MySQL/MariaDB will support `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @Parfait  ... correct ..  who knows .. it is a certain shortcut .. but it is not difficult to overcome ..

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is a `full join`.  One method that often works is `union all` and `group by`:

```
select year, month, max(data) as data, max(data2) as data2
from ((select year, month, data, null as data2
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select year, month, null, data2
       from table2
      )
     ) t
group by year, month;
```